# Collapse navbar not working in mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am trying to get collapse navbar working in mobile device. It is working in web browser, but not in mobile devices. It opens and shuts, but when I click some elements, it is not working.

I inserted my demopage to here, so you can check if you find something out:
http://suomisuvanto.partybazooka.com/

[Link to demo](http://suomisuvanto.partybazooka.com/)